# How can I redirect url in PHP using htaccess

Tags: php, url, redirect

I need some rewrite rules for URLs

I want:

`www.dawsonautodetailing.com/?page=About-Us`

Changed to:

`www.dawsonautodetailing.com/page/About-Us` or `www.dawsonautodetailing.com/About-Us`

I've already created .htaccess into my root folder.

Thank you for the help!

I've tried to google it but since i am new to .htaccess i don't even know where to begin :)

Comment: You can either redirect in php (`header('Location: /'); die();`) or in Apache by config or .htaccess (`RedirectPermanent` or `RewriteRule`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod_rewrite module in Apache to redirect URLs using .htaccess.

To redirect a specific URL, you can use the following syntax in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteRule ^old-url$ http://www.example.com/new-url [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect any requests for the URL "old-url" to "http://www.example.com/new-url" with a "301" redirect (permanent redirect).

You can also use regular expressions to match patterns in the URL and redirect accordingly. For example, if you want to redirect all requests for URLs starting with "old-directory" to "new-directory", you can use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^old-directory/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/new-directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will take any URL starting with "old-directory" and redirect it to the same URL, but starting with "new-directory" instead.

Be careful while modifying htaccess as it can cause website to malfunction. It is always a good practice to take backup before making any changes.

Comment: You example is Apache2 configuration, but it has nothing to do with php. So your first sentence is wrong.